# Put woocommerce category ID in product list shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to include woocommerce category ID in this shortcode:

`[ux_products columns="7" cat="IDNEEDED" out_of_stock="exclude"]`

This function output category ID.

```
function get_my_prod_cat_ids($prod_id) {

$terms = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'product_cat' );
if($terms) {
    foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        $cats_ids_array[$key] = $term->term_id;

        //To get only the first category (uncomment below)
        //break;
    }
    // to get an array replace below by: $output = $cats_ids_array;
    $output = implode( ",", $cats_ids_array ); 
    echo $output;
}
}
```